# Extract all CSS with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am performing some analysis on website complexity.  What is the best way to extract all CSS (external stylesheets, `<style>` tags, and inline CSS), for all nodes in a web page, using headless Chrome/Puppeteer?

I'm ideally looking for compiled CSS, in similar format to the "Styles" tab in the Chrome dev-tools.

Answer (score 4):

You ask for two different things:

**Scraping**

For web scraping in `nodejs` better use `cheerio` package.

**Sniffing network requests**

If you want to get css files requested you can go something like:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('response',async response => {
    if(response.request().resourceType() === 'stylesheet') {
      console.log(await response.text());
    }
  });
  await page.goto('https://myurl.com');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I'm not really interested in "scraping" here.  Instead, I'm looking for *compiled* CSS, which Chrome supplies, but difficult to accomplish with Cheerio.

Comment: You still had the same issue after 2 years? Anyway, thanks to @dinigo and Balmy. I wonder if there is a way to extract internal CSS  using the same approach?

Comment: sorry @intumwa, I'm a little bit rusty on this tech already. Hope you find your answer

Comment: @dinigo, I ended up using regex to extract the internal CSS.